# Configure RedirectMatch for last part without infinite loop

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I am trying to write a 301 `RedirectMatch` in my htaccess file. However the matching url is also triggered on the url I redirect to, resulting in a infinite loop.

When my url ends with `/profile/herman-visser` I want to redirect to `/profile/herman-visser/photos` . I am using the following rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /profile/(.*) /profile/$1/photos
```

This is working however when Im going to `/profile/herman-visser/photos` the rule is also triggered resulting in `/photos/photos/photos/photos` etc

Can someone help me in finding the correct solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exclude the destination you are redirecting to

```
RedirectMatch 301 /profile/((?!.*/photos).*)$ /profile/$1/photos
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution is working however I have more urls that match. How should I exclude all others? Is there a way to exclude the url if after profile/(.*) there is another part

Comment: Thank you updated your solution to the following: Could you add this to your answer if this is valid: RedirectMatch 301 /profile/((?!.*/.*).*)?$ /profile/$1/photos